# Why is the folium map which I am creating not saving to an html file?

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to create a folium map and save it as an html file. The code is running without any error, but no file is being created. The code can be seen here.

```
import pandas  
import folium  
import json  
df = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Jon\Downloads\Webmap_datasources\Volcanoes.txt")

lat = list(df["LAT"])  
lon = list(df["LON"])  
el = list(df["ELEV"])  

map = folium.Map(location =[lat[1],lon[1]], zoom_start=3, tiles= "Stamen Terrain")


folium.GeoJson(data = open(r'C:\Users\Jon\Downloads\Extract+me+json\world.json').read()).add_to(map)

for x,y,z in zip(lat, lon, el):   
    folium.CircleMarker(location= (x,y), popup= str(z)).add_to(map)`
map.save("volc1.html")
```

How can I create this file with all of the information I am trying to incorporate?

Comment: don't name the map `map`, it is a built-in python function

Comment: I changed to 'mapp', but that does not seem to help.